How to cross build static python library (3.12), for embedding, on windows, to any other platform
I'd love to embed python 3.12 into my app, which is a godot app.
My expected targets are windows, linux, and android.
And I want to embed python, and I'm loosing my mind over trying to just build python as a static library.
Other code in my project just uses cmake or scons, when I want to switch between platforms I just tell it here's a different platform.
But with python, there's a separate windows and linux versions? And when building from windows, you're supposed to use PCbuild/build.cmd, which works for windows, but doesn't build for linux or android.
I've tried building python with w64devkit, which wouldn't stop shouting about not knowing the architecture no matter what --build --host parameters I'd put in.
w64devkit\bin\sh -c ./Python-3.12.4/configure --build=x86_64-pc-mingw64 --host=x86_64-Windows_NT
I've tried to build python on MSYS but when running config it warns me about being unsupported, and during build I got a lot of undefined references to different parts of python.
I've tried the project that builds python with cmake, but that one doesn't work for python 3.12.
I've even tried using a rust based python interpreter, but I couldn't get that one running at all.
I'd appreciate any help!
